# Inconsistent peer connection between Android Phone and Watch

Tags: android, listener, wear-os

I want to add Watch module to existing android project. this is the line in phone project androidmanifest:

```
 <application
    android:name="com.xxx.xx.core.xx"
    android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.xx.xx" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
     ....
```

This is the onPeerConnected method:

```
@Override
public void onPeerConnected(Node peer) {
    super.onPeerConnected(peer);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Peer Connected To Phone", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I introduced with a problem. Connection is done sometime. I sometimes see "Peer connected to phone" toast. However, when i deploy new versions to phone and watch, connection fails and i dont see toast message. Any ideas ?

Note: Both have the same package name in their own androidmanifest files

Answer (score 1):

`onPeerConnected` will only be called, if connection state changes. If your app gets reinstalled, then it just arrives in some state and since there is no change, it will not trigger the callback. You need to also explicitly check the connection state using [`NodeApi.getConnectedNodes`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/NodeApi.html#getConnectedNodes(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)).

Comment: I realized that getConnectedNodes says me "it is connected." and also wear sends the message to phone succesfully. However, in this case, onMessageReceived not called. I thought it is problem of peer Connection.  what can be possible problem here ?

Comment: I don't know, you would need to expand how you implemented onMessageReceived. Are you using WearableListenerService or register a listener in an activity?

Comment: i tried it with a new project. It works properly. When i try to connect on existing project like in question, it works inconsistently. ı used wearableListener and androidmanifest is like:

<service android:name="com.xx.xx.wear.ListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </service>

Comment: Can you just use the new project or do you still need help with the old one?

Comment: i am good in new project. However, normally i have to do all things on old project. So, i still have problem. If you find possible solution, just let me know :)